# increase php upload time

Tags: php, upload

I face a problem with uploading files in php script on an external server  wich I have no privileges to edit their files, with small files everything is ok but whene i try to upload a bigger file (not much 27Mb) after 5 minutes I get an error message:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.

I tried all the possible solutions:

1. add a php.ini file in the folder
2. add a .htaccess file

I change the following parameters:

- max_input_time = 900
- upload_max_filesize = 40M
- post_max_size = 40M
- memory_limit = 256M
- I even tried set_time_limit(900) function in my script.

with all this changes when I use phpinfo() function I see that the time and the size are increased but I still have the timeout problem after about 300 seconds.

Is there a solution to this problem ?

Comment: Check webserver logfiles. The maximum execution time doesn't start when you start uploading but when PHP receives the files and starts parsing the script.

Comment: but I don't have access to server files :/

Comment: Then ask server admin for assistance.